# Why are the two results generated?

Tags: python, numpy

```
In [18]: z = np.array([[6,7,3],[8,8,8]])                                                                                                                                                      

In [19]: z                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[19]: 
array([[6, 7, 3],
       [8, 8, 8]])

In [20]: print(z[0:, :0])                                                                                                                                                                     
[]

In [21]: print(z[1:, :1])                                                                                                                                                                     
[[8]]
```

I don't understand the two print statements. For example, z[1:, :1]?

Comment: These are ways to slice an array. You can omit the start or end of a slice, which is interpreted as beginning or end of that dimension. [This](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) might be useful.

Comment: Do you understand the slice notation? With  lists? With 1d arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an array where every value is different:

```
In [134]: z = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
In [135]: z
Out[135]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

Try variations on the 0 slice:

```
In [136]: z[0:,:]
Out[136]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
In [137]: z[:,:0]
Out[137]: array([], shape=(2, 0), dtype=int64)
In [138]: z[0:,:0]
Out[138]: array([], shape=(2, 0), dtype=int64)
```

'0:' is the same as ':' and '::' and `slice(None,None,None)`, all meaning the whole thing or dimension.

':0' means '0:0', which is an empty slice, hence the size 0 dimension.

now variations on the 1 slice:

```
In [139]: z[1:,:]
Out[139]: array([[3, 4, 5]])
In [140]: z[:,:1]
Out[140]: 
array([[0],
       [3]])
In [141]: z[1:,:1]
Out[141]: array([[3]])
```

'1:' all the but the first slice; for the size 2 dimension that is '1:2' a size 1 slice.  ':1' also '0:1' another size 1 slice, hence the (1,1) shape result.